# to detect IPTC content in jpeg image

Tags: java, metadata, jpeg, iptc

I need to know how to check whether given jpeg image has iptc content in it or not ? 
This should be done with java.As i am new to this techonology.
Could someone help regarding this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this library,

http://reader.imagero.com/

supported metadata:

```
IPTC (JPEG, TIFF, EPS, PSD)
EXIF (JPEG, TIFF, PSD)
XMP (JPEG, TIFF, EPS, PSD)
Wang Annotations (read only)
ImageResourceBlock
ImageFileDirectrory
JPEG Markers
```

Get IPTC metadata from one image and insert it in other:

```
String source = "C:\\images\\source.jpg";
String destination = "C:\\images\\destination.jpg";
IOParameterBlock iopb = new IOParameterBlock(source);
iopb.setDestination(destination);
IPTCEntryCollection collection = IPTC.getIPTC(iopb);
IPTC.insertIPTC(collection, iopb);
```

- EDIT (Tutorial):

http://reader.imagero.com/tutorial.html

Answer (score 0):

It simple by using the [Metadata Extractor](http://code.google.com/p/metadata-extractor/), an open source project for reading meta data - hosted on google code.

#### Supported directories

- Exif
- IPTC
- XMP
- JFIF / JFXX
- ICC Profiles
- Photoshop

#### Example

Reading HEADLINE TAG from IPTC Directory. There is an [GettingStarted](http://code.google.com/p/metadata-extractor/w/list) chapter.

```
  File file = new File("input.jpg");

  // read meta data from image
  Metadata metadata = ImageMetadataReader.readMetadata(file);

  // get all existing directories
  metadata.getDirectories();

  // check whether the iptc directory exists
  if (metadata.containsDirectory(IptcDirectory.class))
  {
      // read headline from iptc directory
      IptcDirectory directory = metadata.getDirectory(IptcDirectory.class);
      directory.getString(IptcDirectory.TAG_HEADLINE);
  }
```

#### Camera support

The library also read camera-specific data

- Agfa
- Canon
- Casio
- Epson
- Fujifilm
- Kodak
- Kyocera
- Leica
- Minolta
- Nikon
- Olympus
- Panasonic
- Pentax
- Sanyo
- Sigma/Foveon
- Sony